# How can I overwrite data in Snowflake using snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created one snowpipe in Snowflake.
But I am unable to overwrite my data in it.
Is there a way I can either use delete or overwrite in snow pipe before copying my data?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stored procedure to execute the below task sequentially:

- Truncate the table
- Execute the copy command

If you want to load the data any specific time then you can schedule a stored procedure using task.

Answer (score 1):

It would be normal practice to load the data from Snowpipe into a temporary/staging table and process it there - doubt you can process it in Snowpipe.

Please can you explain in more detail how/why you want to overwrite data in Snowpipe? Can you provide examples of what you are trying to achieve?

**Answer 2**

Snowpipe is used for continuous data loading from a stream, so I'm not sure why you are using it for daily loads of a single dataset?

I would create a standard COPY INTO process and then wrap it in a stored procedure that handles the target table deletion as well. You can then schedule this to run daily.

Comment: I have one table where I am importing a sheet manually on daily basis.
Before uploading the data I am cleaning the table.
I want to automate this process and for that, I created one snowpipe, which is copying data from sheet into the table, But before copying, I want to delete the existing data from that 
table.How can I do that?
I hope I cleared my question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nick.I am new to snowflake.
I am importing file from AWS S3.
Could you please give me one sample code which can help me in understanding that.
Like how can I import excel sheet and create procedure that can work automatically on snowflake.I didn't find any link to upload file from local folder path.

Comment: Hi - this is all covered, including examples, in the documentation. You can't load data directly from a local file, you would need to PUT it into a local stage first (or send it to S3 or equivalent and create an external stage against it)

Comment: Hi Nick,
Did you share some link or documents.I can't find it.

Comment: Hi, I meant the standard Snowflake documentation